# DRF end-point posting error for nested serialization

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

`Get` method working in browse-able api end-point but when i try to post using my end-point through browser, it fires me this error: (My serializers are nested)

[image]

This is my `serializers.py` and it is Nested serilizers

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . models import Author, Article, Category, Organization


class OrganizationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        fields = '__all__'


class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    organization = OrganizationSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = '__all__'


class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = '__all__'


class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = AuthorSerializer()
    category = CategorySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model =  Article
        fields = '__all__'
```

and this is my `models.py`

```
from django.db import models
import uuid

class Organization(models.Model):
    organization_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.organization_name

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    detail = models.TextField()
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Article(models.Model):
    alias = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='author')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and this is my `views.py` ( I am using APIView, not VIewset)

```
class ArticleDeleteUpdate(DestroyAPIView, UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    lookup_field = 'alias'
```

and this is my `urls.py`

```
path('api/v1/article', views.ArticleListCreateGet.as_view(), name='article2'),
```

I worked 10 hours on it to fix the issue but i failed to fix it...

I am not getting whats wrong with this... this error ruined my sleep..

Can anyone help me please to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT with the correct approach:
Sorry I just realized you are using ModelSerializers instead of Serializers.
You need to change from

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = AuthorSerializer()
    category = CategorySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model =  Article
        fields = '__all__'
```

to

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()
    category = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model =  Article
        fields = '__all__'
```

And check the documentation of PrimaryKeyRelatedField as it includes some different options that might be interesting for the design of your API

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield

Most likely you will need the `read_only=True` option so you don't need to override any method

Original answer with a bit of explanation:
You are getting the error because the POST is trying to create the nested objects but your serializer does not override the `.create()` method so the serializer does not know how to handle the nested relationships.

Take a look on https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writing-create-methods-for-nested-representations where you can get a grasp of what you need.

Comment: Sorry your recent suggestion is wrong, coz, if i change llike you suggested, it will not apears nested data

Comment: I am talking about create method, that is why i cant fix it yet

Comment: I need more info to be able to help you, which is the body of the POST? are you creating the author and the categories at the same time than the article?

Comment: Yes, at the same time, i am creating it

Comment: Then you also need to override the create method and assign the author and the categories then save the object.

Comment: I tried to override seeing documentation but i failed... Can you please help me in this case?